# CSS анимированное шестиугольное меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, svg

Я пытаюсь создать анимированное шестиугольное меню.

Пожалуйста, посмотрите для лучшего понимания  рисунок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Гамбургер кнопка в виде шестиугольника находится в центре.
После нажатия на неё отображаются треугольные фигуры, окружающие кнопку гамбургера.
Значок гамбургера превращается в крест, чтобы при повторном нажатии на него вернуть всё в исходное положение.
*В моей поясняющей картинке на самом деле отсутствует  один шаг в самом начале. На левой половине картинки должна отображаться только кнопка гамбургера.*

Поэтому мой вопрос заключается в следующем:

Как  создавать эту анимацию из шестиугольника с помощью  `HTML`, `CSS` через `jQuery` или другими способами.

Какие способы вы бы использовали, чтобы сделать это?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [CSS animated hexagon menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29717765/7394871) от участника  [@Julian Livin' in China](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050487/julian-livin-in-china).</sub>

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29717765/7394871

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Вариант с CSS-переменными + `clip-path`. Тут не вся функциональность, это лишь набросок, но идея, думаю, понятна.

UPD: добавил кнопку и еще немного причесал код.

```js
document.querySelector('.menu__btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.menu').classList.toggle('menu--open');
});
```

```css
:root {
  --side: 200px;
  --a: 25% 5%;
  --b: 75% 5%;
  --c: 100% 50%;
  --d: 75% 95%;
  --e: 25% 95%;
  --f: 0% 50%;
  --g: 50% 50%;
  --x: 0;
  --y: 0;
  --coordAfter: 25px;
}

.menu {
  width: var(--side);
  height: var(--side);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.menu__list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu__triangle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: transform .25s, opacity .25s;
  background-color: #d261ff;
  width: var(--side);
  height: var(--side);
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu__triangle:hover {
  background-color: #9c29c1;
}

.menu--open .menu__triangle {
  transform: translate3d(var(--x), var(--y), 0);
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu__btn {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #250031;
  clip-path: polygon(var(--a), var(--b), var(--c), var(--d), var(--e), var(--f));
  font-size: 0;
  width: calc(var(--side) / 6);
  height: calc(var(--side) / 6);
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu__btn:hover,
.menu--open .menu__btn {
  background-color: #613175;
}

.menu__btn-dash {
  width: calc(var(--side) / 14.285);
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.menu__btn-dash:after {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: transform .2s;
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
}

.menu--open .menu__btn-dash:after {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.menu__1 {
  clip-path: polygon(var(--a), var(--b) , var(--g));
  --y: calc(var(--coordAfter) * -1);
}

.menu__2 {
  clip-path: polygon(var(--g), var(--b), var(--c));
  --y: calc(var(--coordAfter) * -1/2);
  --x: var(--coordAfter);
}

.menu__3 {
  clip-path: polygon(var(--g), var(--c), var(--d));
  --y: calc(var(--coordAfter) / 2);
  --x: var(--coordAfter);
}

.menu__4 {
  clip-path: polygon(var(--e), var(--g), var(--d));
  --y: var(--coordAfter);
}

.menu__5 {
  clip-path: polygon(var(--f), var(--g), var(--e));
  --x: calc(var(--coordAfter) * -1);
  --y: calc(var(--coordAfter) / 2);
}

.menu__6 {
  clip-path: polygon(var(--f), var(--a), var(--g));
  --x: calc(var(--coordAfter) * -1);
  --y: calc(var(--coordAfter) * -1/2);
}
```

```html
<menu class="menu">
  <button class="menu__btn">
    <span class="menu__btn-dash">Toggle menu</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="menu__list">
    <li class="menu__triangle menu__1">1</li>
    <li class="menu__triangle menu__2">2</li>
    <li class="menu__triangle menu__3">3</li>
    <li class="menu__triangle menu__4">4</li>
    <li class="menu__triangle menu__5">5</li>
    <li class="menu__triangle menu__6">6</li>
  </ul>
</menu>
```

Comment: спасибо! (+), а серединку шестиугольник с анимацией  добавить? Можно отдельным постом-ответом, но все элементы анимации  вместе желательно, а не только треугольники

Comment: @Alexandr_TT ну теперь вроде бы всё )

Comment: замечательно! А почему не оформил отдельным ответом второй вариант, я же не смогу поставить тебе второй плюс :) И людям было бы полезней смотреть, как поэтапно решается задача от простого к сложному.  Ну я не хочу напрягать, исключительно твоё желание важно. Если хочешь остановиться прямо сейчас, просто поставлю галочку, напиши пожалуйста. Какое примешь решение

Comment: так это же не принципиально новое решение, чтобы это был отдельный ответ, а насчет плюсов — это совсем не страшно )
больше дорабатывать ответ уже не буду.

Comment: хорошо, Твоё решение зачтено.

Answer (score 20):

Вот пример и демонстрация:

### [Hexagon menu demo](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/WvNQpG)

И вот анимация  `gif`  шестиугольника в действии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Основные функции меню шестиугольника:

- **адаптивность** - в зависимости от размера `viewport` `(vmin)`. Это можно изменить, изменив значения `width/height` на проценты
  (соотношение сторон должно поддерживаться см. [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-maintain-div-aspect-ratio))
- Изображения (с тегом `<img />`), титры и субтитры
- 6 пунктов меню
- анимированный значок гамбургера в шестиугольном контуре
- границы пунктов меню привязаны к треугольникам, чтобы они не
  перекрывали друг друга. Таким образом, событие `click` и `hover state` запускаются только тогда, когда фактический элемент меню - `hovered/clicked`
- Может отображаться над изображениями, градиентами или любыми
  неосновными фонами

### Шестиугольная компоновка:

- `CSS3 2d transforms` позволяет создавать треугольники `skewY()` и
  `rotate()`
- элементы меню привязаны к треугольникам с помощью классов - `.tr` и
  `.clip`, `unskewed` с `.clip` и возврат поворота связан с классом
  `.content`, форма шестиугольника вокруг гамбургера выполнена
  полигоном `SVG` (легче сделать и получить лучший результат, чем с
  `CSS`
- Значок гамбургера выполнен с помощью `span` и двумя псевдоэлементами

### Шестиугольное меню с анимацией:

- треугольники переходят один за другим (`translate()` и `opacity`) со
  свойством `transition-delay`
- "bounce effect" для треугольника с анимацией производится с помощью
  функции `transition-timming-function` и кубической кривой безье.
- Значок гамбургера для перекрестной анимации создается путем перехода
  двух псевдоэлементов (`translate()` и `rotate()`) и затухания фона
  центральных элементов до прозрачного цвета `rgba`

### Hover анимация :

- эффект наведения гамбургера  достигается путем анимации свойства
  `stroke-dashoffset` элемента SVG `<polygon>`.
- названия элементов и субтитры отображаются при наведении с
  использованием `3D transforms` (`translateZ()`) и непрозрачности.
  Изображения одновременно исчезают

### Используемая технология:

- `CSS` кодируется с помощью `SCSS` и `Autoprefixer`, чтобы упростить
  запись, чтение и сокращение.   Вы можете увидеть скомпилированный
  `CSS`, нажав кнопку    `Скомпилированный вид` в демоверсии
  (скомпилированный CSS также доступен в конце этого сообщения)
- Использован `SVG` для шестиугольника вокруг иконки гамбургера
- `HTML` для разметки
- простой JS для переключения анимации с добавлением класса на
  контейнере

### Поддержка браузерами:

- Я тестировал это меню на `IE 11`, `chrome`, `FF` и `opera` в системе
  `Windows` и меню работает во всех этих браузерах.
- `Chrome` и `FF` визуализируют шрифт с размытием (как видно в
  анимированном `gif`, сделанном из хрома), и `FF` имеет тенденцию
  создавать зубчатые стороны для треугольников
- `IE 11` имеет наилучшее качество для шрифтов и треугольников, но он
  не поддерживает анимацию `SMIL` и, следовательно, не оказывает
  эффекта наведения на шестиугольник гамбургера
- Я использовал тестирование [`crossbrowser`](http://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/test-center) для проверки поддержки
  `safari`, и в этой системе также работает шестиугольное меню.

```js
var hexNav = document.getElementById('hexNav');

document.getElementById('menuBtn').onclick = function() {
    var className = ' ' + hexNav.className + ' ';
    if ( ~className.indexOf(' active ') ) {
        hexNav.className = className.replace(' active ', ' ');
    } else {
        hexNav.className += ' active';
    }              
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #E3DFD2;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 70vmin;
  height: 70vmin;
  min-width: 500px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/** MENU BUTTON ******************************************/
#menuBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  will-change: transform;
}
#menuBtn svg {
  display: block;
}
#menuBtn:hover svg polygon {
  -webkit-animation: hexHover 0.7s;
          animation: hexHover 0.7s;
}
#menuBtn span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-color: #585247;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
          transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
#menuBtn span:before, #menuBtn span:after {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #585247;
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
          transition: transform 0.5s;
}
#menuBtn span:before {
  top: 0;
}
#menuBtn span:after {
  bottom: 0px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hexHover {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0,0,300;
  }
  10% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0,20,300;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 300,20,300;
  }
}

@keyframes hexHover {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0,0,300;
  }
  10% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0,20,300;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 300,20,300;
  }
}
/** MENU ITEMS *******************************************/
#hex {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1) translatez(0);
      -ms-transform: scale(0.1) translatez(0);
          transform: scale(0.1) translatez(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.05s 0.5s;
          transition: transform 0.05s 0.5s;
}

.tr {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 34.6%;
  height: 40%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
          transform-origin: 0 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg);
      -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg);
          transform: skewY(-30deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

.tr:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-30deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-30deg);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
          transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}
.tr:nth-child(1) .clip {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
          transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
}
.tr:nth-child(1) .content {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
          transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
      -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
          transform-origin: 0 0;
  padding-left: 15%;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 30% 70%;
          perspective-origin: 30% 70%;
}

.active .tr:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
      -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
          transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.05s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.05s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
          transition: opacity 0.5s 0.05s, transform 0.5s 0.05s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
}

.tr:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-30deg);
          transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-30deg);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
          transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}
.tr:nth-child(2) .clip {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
          transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
}
.tr:nth-child(2) .content {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
          transform: rotate(-90deg);
  top: -8%;
  left: 6.67%;
  padding-left: 30%;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 30% 50%;
          perspective-origin: 30% 50%;
}

.active .tr:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
      -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
          transform: rotate(60deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.1s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.1s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
          transition: opacity 0.5s 0.1s, transform 0.5s 0.1s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
}

.tr:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-30deg);
          transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-30deg);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
          transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}
.tr:nth-child(3) .clip {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
          transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
}
.tr:nth-child(3) .content {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-150deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-150deg);
          transform: rotate(-150deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 42.3% 36.5%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 42.3% 36.5%;
          transform-origin: 42.3% 36.5%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 30% 30%;
          perspective-origin: 30% 30%;
}

.active .tr:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
      -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
          transform: rotate(120deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.15s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.15s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
          transition: opacity 0.5s 0.15s, transform 0.5s 0.15s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
}

.tr:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-30deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-30deg);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
          transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}
.tr:nth-child(4) .clip {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
          transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
}
.tr:nth-child(4) .content {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-210deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-210deg);
          transform: rotate(-210deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 65.4% 38.4%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 65.4% 38.4%;
          transform-origin: 65.4% 38.4%;
  padding-left: 30%;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 70% 30%;
          perspective-origin: 70% 30%;
}

.active .tr:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
      -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
          transform: rotate(180deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
          transition: opacity 0.5s 0.2s, transform 0.5s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
}

.tr:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-30deg);
          transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-30deg);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
          transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}
.tr:nth-child(5) .clip {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
          transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
}
.tr:nth-child(5) .content {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-270deg);
          transform: rotate(-270deg);
  top: -8%;
  left: 6.67%;
  padding-left: 15%;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 70% 50%;
          perspective-origin: 70% 50%;
}

.active .tr:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
      -ms-transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
          transform: rotate(240deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.25s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.25s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
          transition: opacity 0.5s 0.25s, transform 0.5s 0.25s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
}

.tr:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-30deg);
          transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-30deg);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
          transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}
.tr:nth-child(6) .clip {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
          transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
}
.tr:nth-child(6) .content {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-330deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-330deg);
          transform: rotate(-330deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 106.7% 25.2%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 106.7% 25.2%;
          transform-origin: 106.7% 25.2%;
  padding-left: 30%;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 70% 70%;
          perspective-origin: 70% 70%;
}

.active .tr:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
      -ms-transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
          transform: rotate(300deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
          transition: opacity 0.5s 0.3s, transform 0.5s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
}

.tr:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) skewY(-30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) skewY(-30deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg) skewY(-30deg);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
          transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}
.tr:nth-child(7) .clip {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
          transform: skewY(30deg) rotate(30deg);
}
.tr:nth-child(7) .content {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-390deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-390deg);
          transform: rotate(-390deg);
}

.active .tr:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
      -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
          transform: rotate(360deg) skewY(-30deg) translate(10%, -10%);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.35s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
          transition: opacity 0.5s 0.35s, transform 0.5s 0.35s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1);
}

.clip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 116%;
  height: 86.66%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
      -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
          transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 86.6%;
  height: 116%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 2vmin;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
          perspective: 500px;
  background: #000;
}
.content img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
          transition: opacity 0.3s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.content h2, .content p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px);
          transform: translateZ(-50px);
}
.content h2 {
  bottom: 50%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2em;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1), opacity 0.3s;
          transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1), opacity 0.3s;
}
.content p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 1em;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s 0.075s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1), opacity 0.3s 0.075s;
          transition: transform 0.3s 0.075s cubic-bezier(0, 2.3, 0.8, 1), opacity 0.3s 0.075s;
}
.content:hover h2, .content:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
      -ms-transform: translatez(0);
          transform: translatez(0);
}
.content:hover img {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.active #menuBtn:hover svg polygon {
  -webkit-animation: none;
          animation: none;
}
.active #menuBtn span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.active #menuBtn span:before {
  -webkit-transform: translatey(8px) rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: translatey(8px) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translatey(8px) rotate(45deg);
}
.active #menuBtn span:after {
  -webkit-transform: translatey(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: translatey(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translatey(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}
.active #hex {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) translatez(0);
      -ms-transform: scale(0.9) translatez(0);
          transform: scale(0.9) translatez(0);
  -webkit-transition: none;
          transition: none;
  will-change: transform;
}
.active .tr {
  opacity: 1;
  will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<nav id="hexNav">
  <div id="menuBtn">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
      <polygon points="50 2 7 26 7 74 50 98 93 74 93 26" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#585247" stroke-dasharray="0,0,300"/>
    </svg>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <ul id="hex">
    <li class="tr"><div class="clip"><a href="#" class="content">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7435/13629508935_62a5ddf8ec_c.jpg" alt="" />
      <h2 class="title">Title</h2><p>Catch phrase</p>
    </a></div></li>
    <li class="tr"><div class="clip"><a href="#" class="content">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
      <h2 class="title">Title</h2><p>Catch phrase</p>
    </a></div></li>
    <li class="tr"><div class="clip"><a href="#" class="content">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h2 class="title">Title</h2><p>Catch phrase</p>
    </a></div></li>
    <li class="tr"><div class="clip"><a href="#" class="content">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6092/6227418584_d5883b0948.jpg" alt="" />
      <h2 class="title">Title</h2><p>Catch phrase</p>
    </a></div></li>
    <li class="tr"><div class="clip"><a href="#" class="content">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt="" />
      <h2 class="title">Title</h2><p>Catch phrase</p>
    </a></div></li>
    <li class="tr"><div class="clip"><a href="#" class="content">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg" alt="" />
      <h2 class="title">Title</h2><p>Catch phrase</p>
    </a></div></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [CSS animated hexagon menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29721362/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>

Comment: Ты как всегда на высоте))))